# Xamarin forms get current location take more time

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, geolocation, android-gps

I have xamarin forms app and have functionality to capture current user location and i using CrossGeolocator PLugin
and these part of code for get location:

```
   locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
   var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
   order.@long = position.Longitude;
   order.lat = position.Latitude;
```

its return location but some times take more time to return current location is there any solution to decrease location capture time.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to speed up the process - use `Xamarin.Essentials`. Xamarin.Essentials provides an excellent way to get the users location which is a **faster alternative** than using the Geolocator Plugin. Not only that - Xamarin.Essentials is tested well and is backed by Microsoft itself.

First of all paste the following code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
```

Here is an example of getting the user's latitude and longitude - you can adapt the code below to your project:

```
var position = await Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();

            double latitude = position.Latitude;

            double longitude = position.Longitude;
```

For more info regarding GeoLocation go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android.

**You should notice a significant difference in speed when you use `Xamarin.Essentials`.**

Comment: Indeed. With Geolocator you sacrifice speed, but according to [James](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/303/503646481) you gain precision.